# how do i switch custom kernels?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, linux-kernel

i have created and installed a new kernel in my ubuntu system, but now i have added a new system call and created a new kernel, how do i set this new kernel as the one the OS should boot from.

```
dpkg -i kernel-image-2.6.deb
```

i tried this on my first kernel and this set the kernel to this one

then i added a new system call
compiled the new kernel
and called

```
dpkg -i kernel-image-2.6.Custom.deb
```

but now when i reboot it stays as the older kernel,

any ideas on how to switch kernels?????

thank you

Answer (score 2):

the answer here may be grub.

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/

also try holding down shift

these threads may help

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-45362.html
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1520821

Comment: i am using vmware fusion on my mac, so how do i get grub to boot prior to the automatic loading of the kernel

Comment: did you try shift?

Comment: sweet cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you install a kernel image produced by the normal packaging system, the new kernel is registered with the bootloader. The command to do this is indicated by the `postinst_hook` setting in `/etc/kernel-img.conf`; the default is `update-grub`.

With Grub2 (the default bootloader), under the default configuration, you will not see a menu at boot time unless you have another operating system besides Ubuntu. You can make the menu appear at boot time by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> when your computer boots (press the key after the BIOS has initialized the keyboard and hold it until the Grub menu appears). If you want the menu to always appear, edit [`/etc/default/grub`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#grub) and comment out the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` setting. You can change the default booted kernel through the `GRUB_DEFAULT` setting.